# java compilation error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2

I'm expiriencing multiple compilation errors in my project, most of the code is in red, but the strange(or not) thing is that while building the project with maven everything is build successfully and the war is assemled as it should be.

The thing is that auto suggest is not working because code is not compiling. What can I do to fix this?

I'm using eclipse, sorry

UPDATE:

I've tried all suggestions below but none worked

Comment: What's the IDE you are using?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, have you installed the m2Eclipse plugin?  Your IDE is likely not set up to handle maven projects correctly and as such, does not recognize that the classpath should include all of your maven dependencies.

Comment: If you are using eclipse, maven can configure an eclipse project for you using `mvn eclipse:eclipse`.

Comment: I find it amazing that you've bothered to tell us that the current answers haven't helped... but you still haven't told us what compilation errors you're seeing.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Classes cannot be found/resolved, as if I don't have dependencies, but I do actually and this is wierd

Comment: @London: How have you told Eclipse about those dependencies though? Are they on your project's build path? Can you give us screenshots of your project build path dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's Eclipse do

```
Project > Clean
```

then right click at the parent-most project and do

```
Maven > Update Project Configuration
Maven > Update Dependencies
```

I guess you have m2eclipse installed, already.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse, try Project > clean.. your project.

I don't know why, but Eclipse sometimes just think your project was wrong but it's not. Clean it to entirely build it again.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what IDE you're using or what the errors are, which makes it pretty hard to give you advice. My guess is that you haven't configured your project (or whatever the equivalent IDE concept is) to tell it the libraries you're using... whereas the Maven build file already contains that information.

EDIT: Okay, so it can't find the right libraries. Options:

- Use a Maven plugin and let it manage the project
- Edit the project's build path and explicitly tell it which jar files to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use a maven plugin in your IDE

[plugin for eclipse](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html)
[plugin for netbeans](http://maven.apache.org/netbeans-module.html)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have to include external libraries/dependencies in your IDE. It seems when you're building with maven, those dependencies are solved for you.

Some IDE's support Maven projects, try to see if yours does.